# Restore SIM Card details to PC

Tags: sim-card

I have my SIM card from the back of my Samsung Galaxy S5. However, I do not have the phone anymore. I will not be getting a new phone for quite sometime.
My question is; is there a way to retrieve the entire contents of my SIM card, without having a phone? Maybe there is a way to download the contents to my pc. Please advise

Comment: Can you borrow a phone for a few mins? You could copy all your numbers etc to that phone, then backup to Google or elsewhere? Otherwise you'll need hardware to connect a SIM to the PC.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy SIM card readers for PCs, which will come with Windows software to retrieve any phone numbers and SMS messages from the SIM card. Just search your local Amazon site or eBay for *SIM card reader*. Be careful not to get an SD card reader by accident!

Do bear in mind that most Android phones don't store contacts on the SIM card by default, but on the phone itself. The SIM card can only store very limited information about contacts: just a name and a number. Unless you're sure you've moved all your data onto the SIM card, you might put a lot of time into finding a reader only to find the SIM card is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your carrier, if they have a store, should also have the equipment for this and should do it for free.

You can back them up and probably use a dummy phone or gateway to sync them somewhere so this isn't an issue in the future.

If you currently do not have a carrier, they may still do it for free or for a small fee depending.